# What are the correct keys for sub controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, i18n-tasks

I have a file that is located:
`app/controllers/api/v1/users/searches_controller.rb`

This file starts as following:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Users
      class SearchesController < ActionController::API
```

And I have this code:

`I18n.t('.search')`

When I say

`i18n-tasks missing`

It wants to put my key like thins:
`.search`

Which is not in the way I would like which is

```
api:
  v1:
    users:
      searches_controller:
      .......
```

When I say:

`t('.search')`

I get an error with: `NoMethodError - undefined method`t' for ....`

But `i18n-tasks missing` gives me the keys as following:

```
api:
    v1:
      users:
        searches:
          users_with_email_or_username:
          .......
```

Am I doing something wrong or?

Comment: I'm not sure it's your problem but, if you're using the `t` shortcut, without I18n before, it should be `t('.seach')` instead of `.t('.search')` (remove the dot). With the dot, rails tries to apply the `t` method to nothing and throws an error

Comment: @escanxr that would be a `SyntaxError` though. OP what is the actual issue? To use lazy lookup you have to follow convention which would be `searches` not `searches_controller` if you want to use a full lookup then you should be fine `I18n.t('api.v1.users.searches_controller.[whatever]')`

Comment: @escanxr Yes, the dot is a mistake, the call is `t('search')
@engineersmnky Yes, I would like searches, not searches controller, but this is what I18n-tasks gives me, when I use `i18n-tasks missing`